# My for loop in google script is running through the code but not bringing back the correct response

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script

I'm setting up a loop that looks at 1 spreadsheet and calculates a number based on 2 dates. Then it opens another spreadsheet (name unknown, but created through a different function). based on the number it goes to a particular column, so if the number is less than 7 then column 2 (week 1), if between 7 & 14 goes to column 3(week 2) etc. It then calculates another number based on when spreadsheet was last updated and formats the cell based on that calculation. Then it opens up the next spreadsheet and does the same thing... Theoretically! The code is looping through all the spreadsheets, and the code for the difference is outputting the correct number, but it is putting the response from the first spreadsheet into each of the cells.. it is stopping when it has looped through each of the spreadsheets

I've tried changing where it loops from. I've changing the loop paramenters. I've researched lots of different possibilities.. but maybe have looked at it for too long now!

```
function trackingSheetUpdate() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Campaign');
var trackSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');
var now = new Date();
var rowData = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 
sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();


for (var i = 2; i < rowData.length + 1; i++) {
    var createDate = sourceSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    var NoOfDays = (now - createDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // i've now got the difference between creation date and today's date as a number 
    var diff = Math.round(NoOfDays);
    var getUpdate = sourceSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue(); //this is getting the URL that needs to be opened
    var openSheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(getUpdate).getSheetByName('Sheet1') // this opens the sheet
    var row = openSheet.getLastRow() // this counts the number of rows in Sheet 1
    var weeklyUpdate = openSheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue(); //this gets the value in column 1 of the last row
    var calc = (now - weeklyUpdate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) // makes the date into a number (I hope!)
    var calcDate = Math.round(calc) // this rounds it to a whole number
    Logger.log(diff)


    if (diff > 1 && diff <= 7) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 2).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 7 && diff <= 14) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 3).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 14 && diff <= 21) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 4).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 21 && diff <= 28) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 5).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 28 && diff <= 35) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 6).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 35 && diff <= 42) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 7).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 42 && diff <= 49) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 8).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 49 && diff <= 56) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 9).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 56 && diff <= 63) {
        trackSheet.getRange(i, 10).activateAsCurrentCell()
    } else if (diff > 63 && diff <= 70) {


    if (calcDate <= 7) {

trackSheet.getCurrentCell().setValue("Y").setBackground('#9EEF95')
    } else {

trackSheet.getCurrentCell().setValue("N").setBackground('#F65A5A')
    }
}
}
```

From the spreadsheets I have, it should be showing some data in columns 1, 2 and 3.. but only showing data in column 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code as posted, the only obvious issues are that your ultimate `setValue()`s are within the last `else if` block (63-70 days), and you're missing a `}` at the end of your function. Check that that's not the case on Google Apps Script; if it is, the second most likely issue would be that your sheet's information doesn't differ how you think it does. Try using `Logger.log()` on the values you are reading to make sure they are what you're expecting.

Additional advice: check the [GAS best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices); especially on using batch operations--e.g., you'll get better results reading in only the values you need from the first sheet in a single `getValues()` and then iterating over those arrays (e.g, `array[i][0]`), rather than using separate calls to `getValue()` on every loop. I'm also not sure where you intend to use `rowData` in this script--that's a big request to just check the length (compared to, e.g. a single column).

I'd also still recommend replacing all those if statements with, e.g.

```
var weeknum = (diff-(diff%7))/7 + 1;
var myCell =  trackSheet.getRange(i, weeknum)

calcDate <= 7 ? myCell.setValue("Y").setBackground('#9EEF95') : myCell.setValue("N").setBackground('#F65A5A')
```

This would help a lot with legibility, and avoiding errors like this.

As an example of what I mean, check the below code (untested; may need some small adjustments/fixing:

```
function trackingSheetUpdate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Campaign');
  var trackSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');
  var now = new Date();
  var createDates = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 6, sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  var urls = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 5, sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues(); 

  for (var i = 2; i < urls.length; i++) {
      var NoOfDays = (now - createDates[(i-2)][0]) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
      var diff = Math.round(NoOfDays);    
      var openSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urls[(i-2)][0]).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var row = openSheet.getLastRow();
      var weeklyUpdate = openSheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
      var calc = (now - weeklyUpdate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
      var calcDate = Math.round(calc);
      Logger.log(diff)

      var weeknum = (diff-(diff%7))/7 + 1;
      var myCell =  trackSheet.getRange(i, weeknum)
      calcDate <= 7 ? myCell.setValue("Y").setBackground('#9EEF95') : myCell.setValue("N").setBackground('#F65A5A')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I have started to use the modulo formula.. but couldn't get it to work properly, so thought I would park it as an improvement, until I had got the rest working... but will be using it, once I work out how to increment it.... I need to run the code on a weekly basis.. and wasn't sure if it would do it? I'm usually a VB girl... so this is all a bit new to me.. That } isnt missing in the google code too..I have logged out the difference and the first 2 are 12 and the last 2 are 5, so they should be in different columns... Think I'm going to have to look again

Comment: What are you looking to increment exactly?

Comment: The user spreadsheet is auto generated when they subscribed, so I don't know the name of it in advance. so it looks up and opens the URL. Then I was trying to increment down the user spreadsheet and track whether they had updated their sheet in the last 7 days, then against their line in the tracking sheet, highlight red if they hadn't and green if they had. Talking to the client yesterday, we have decided to change it anyway and if they don't complete a week, they stay on that week until they do complete it. which has made my life a lot easier. I think the new code works. Thank you so much